how can I implement a multiprocessing subprocess which returns a generator
I have a python class which are designed to perform two tasks:

generate some streaming texts by calling LLM api
do some mongoDB queries

A sample class definition is as below:
import multiprocessing
from pymongo import MongoClient


class Testing:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def generate(self):
        llm = LLM_Collection()
        resp = llm.call_llm_openai_cli("kimi",[{"role":"user","content":"hello"}],stream=True)
        return resp
        
        for chunk in resp:
            if not chunk.choices:
                continue
            print(chunk.choices[0].delta.content)
            

    def some_task(self):
        import time
        print("******************************* I slept *******************************")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("******************************* I woke *******************************")
        return "sleep done"
    

    def main(self):
        
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            # generate_proc = pool.apply_async(self.generate)
            task_proc = pool.apply_async(self.some_task)
            
            task_res = task_proc.get()
            # generator = generate_proc.get()
            generator = self.generate()
            for msg in generator:
                print(msg)
        return

I want to make the two tasks done in parallel because they don't really depend on each other's output to run. However, when I run this main() function, the code keeps running with no any outputs.
I tried both having the generator function in the subprocess as well as running it in the main process but neither worked.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Are you looking for yeild from llm.call_llm_openai_cli(...) by chance?
